# getting txt from multiple spans with python selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, text, text-extraction

I would like to get the text value of a span class "currency-coins value" to be used in a comparison.

Basically I want to check the market value of a specific player. I get the player listed 20 times in a container. So the "currency-coins value" is shown 20 times on the page.

[image: span class = currency-coins Value]

Now I need to get the "200" as shown in the screenshot of the HTML code above as value I can work with. And this for all 20 results on the page. The value might be different for all 20 results.

After I got all 20 values, I want to check which one is the lowest.

I will then afterwards use the lowest value as price to list my element on the market.

Is there a way to do this? Since I am learning python for a bit more than one week now, I cant figure it out myself.

Comment: Can you share the code that you have already tried?

Comment: What part are you having troubles with? did you try solving it by yourself? share the code you tried.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to first iterate over the player containers - usually, these are table rows, and, for each container, locate that price element within. For instance:

```
for row in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table tbody > tr"):
    coin_value = float(row.find_element_by_css_selector(".currency-coins.value").text)
    print(coin_value)
```

Note that `table tbody > tr` is used as an example, your locator for table rows or player containers is likely different.